# Is there a way to "smart" auto-reduce the amount of vertices?

Tags: height-map

I made a height map based on a displacement, with a very high vertex count.
However, some parts of the map are flat because the terrain actually... is flat.
I have now 1 million vertices, of which at least 80% are quite useless.

So:
I would like to mass-dissolve vertices that are:
- adjacent to each other
- same height
...so that the flat parts of the terrain would become simplified, to reduce unnecessary vertices (and thus file size and CPU effort etc)
[image: Screenshot edit mode]

I do want to keep the steep hills and canyons with a lot of detail of course, as you can see on the lower half of the image. It's just the flat parts I want simplified.

Is there a way to do this without doing it manually? Because that would take ages.

PS: I tried "limited dissolve" but that kills the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can select one top face, then <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Similar > Normal*, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subivide*.

[image]

Also, you have the *Decimate* modifier / *Planar* mode that will unsubdivide all the faces on the same normal orientation, or according to a certain angle threshold, it will allow you to preserve all the details:

[image]

Comment: The modifier crashes my computer :-) But that seems powerful. So I tried the first option, which is "ok", but would still take some work... But true, less work!

Comment: Ooh too bad, maybe try with a previous version of Blender? But it might be because it's too much to calculate...

Comment: When I have a very slight slope, It actually looks like very long flat steps. Is there a way to have that simplified to "actually a continuous slope" in stead of planes going down one by one?

Comment: I think I'm gonna lasso those parts and un-subdivide.... that kind of does the trick